# TYPO3 v11: upgrade to PHP8 breaks the page completely

Tags: php, typo3, upgrade

I have a working TYPO3 11.5.36 with PHP 7.4.21 (non-composer-install). If I move to PHP 8.1.9 the site gets broken, and it's weird because if I delete all cachefiles in filesystem (typo3temp/var/cache) I can

- access a page, e.g. the backend login form **ONCE** =>
- cache files are written again =>
- after that the next request shows a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET (because the Apache
  child dies/restarts, too) =>
- backend/frontend is not working any more
- no useful log entries

If I disable ~10 **system** extensions in PackageStates.php like tstemplate, sys_note, setup, ... I can access the site, but have all the backend stuff missing of course. If I enable one of this system extensions again, the site breaks again. BTW: Installtool is accessible all the time, but flushing the cache throws an error then, too.

Any suggestions on this behaviour or did I miss something with PHP**8**?

Comment: TYPO3 v11 LTS is compatible with PHP v8.1. It's unlikely that a system extension causes this behaviour. Have you tried to disable all third-party extensions? Maybe one of them extends the functionality of a system extension and is incompatible with PHP v8.

Comment: May I suggest to extend your question and explain what "site is broken" and "backend/frontend is not working" exactly means? What do you see in your browser? A white page? Any error messages? Have you enabled debug output in TYPO3?

Comment: Ok thank you for clarifiying this. Therefore there could only be a problem with the WAMP system I use, so I did a quick replace of PHP8.1 to PHP 8.3 and voila, it's working! TY! 
It just came to my mind, that I tried another fresh WAMP system yesterday (laragon), with PHP8.1, and it was not working either. So for fellows: there is maybe a problem with Win/Apache/PHP8.1 running TYPO3.